# Way to extract Google Synonyms

Tags: synonym

Would anyone know of a way to extract Google Synonyms, either through their API or other (TOS-approved) methods?

Specifically, Google have a function that allows you to type a tilde sign "~" in front of a word to conduct a search with synonyms.

As opposed to the search results, I'd like to extract the actual synonym data - so for ~cat, I would like a script that returns feline, kitten, etc.

http://www.synonymlab.com/ do something similar, I guess - but do they do this through the API?

Sorry but there's limited information out there. Any ideas if it's possible?

Comment: You could try e-mailing Synonym Lab.  I found the e-mail `support@synonymlab.com` off of [Whois](http://whois.domaintools.com/synonymlab.com).

Comment: Hi,

Thanks strager - from what I could research, it seems they run a script that runs a search and extracts the bold letters from the search results, but not sure if that contradicts the TOS. I'll take your advice and drop them a line. If anyone else knows of a way through the API that would be great :)

Thanks,
P.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want Google's? OO makes theirs available as per this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4175371/1416258

Answer (score 5):

I [looked around for a Google synonym API](https://www.google.com/?q=site%3agoogle.com+synonym+api) and found no evidence of such as service.

On the other hand, I found evidence that [other people also looked and found nothing](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-ajax-search-api/ErSW1QKOeMU/cvsNJt5SKGoJ). :)

As alternatives, you might consider using [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/), Freebase (see [a discussion on synonyms](http://lists.freebase.com/pipermail/developers/2009-April/002796.html)), or Wikipedia (see [Extracting Named Entities and Synonyms from Wikipedia](http://www.idi.ntnu.no/~noervaag/papers/AINA2010.pdf)).

Answer (score 0):

The Google Doesn't provide an API for Synonyms. However, A great API Service for Synonyms is http://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/synonyms . It will allows you to request 5000/pm.

Comment: It is crappy.. worse than a dictionary.. do not know what bing is mining for words like - "destroy", "replace" etc.. Totally worthless!!

Answer (score 0):

I found this. This provides unlimited JSON response for the word you want to search.
https://dictionaryapi.dev/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33638871)